# apoyo con mysql y php lista de analisis clinico en un solo registro por usuario

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos días tardes comunidad, tengo la siguiente duda y he estado todo el día de ayer y hoy por mas que intento no puedo seguir adelante.

Tengo esta consulta de bd que hago a mi base de datos:

```
SELECT detalle_factura.id_producto,productos.id_producto,productos.nombre_producto,facturas.id_factura,facturas.numero_factura,facturas.fecha_factura,facturas.id_cliente,clientes.nombre_cliente 

FROM facturas INNER JOIN clientes ON facturas.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente inner join detalle_factura ON facturas.numero_factura = detalle_factura.numero_factura INNER JOIN productos ON detalle_factura.id_producto = productos.id_producto

WHERE detalle_factura.numero_factura = facturas.numero_factura and detalle_factura.id_producto = productos.id_producto and CAST(facturas.fecha_factura AS DATE) = '2021-05-09'
```

la cual quiero que me arroje el usuario y todos los estudios de análisis clinico que se realizo en una solo registro pero me los desglosa por registro múltiple, quiero que me lo arroje asi:

```
juan carlos, quimica clinica - biometria hematica - reacciones febriles, 10/05/2021
```

, todo esto en una tabla. y no así:

```
juan carlos, quimica clinica, 10/05/2021
juan carlos, biometria hematica, 10/05/2021
juan carlos, reacciones febriles, 10/05/2021
```

ya que lo imprimo en php en una tabla pero me los desglosa varias veces con todos los estudios si **por ejemplo juan se hizo análisis 1, 2 y 3 quiero que esos estudios aparezca en un solo registro de mi tabla y no apareza varias veces juan con los estudios por separado.**

Excelente dia.

Comment: buen día compañero, yo soy medico y programador, estas concatenando 3 registros en tu ejemplo, me parece que no seria el objetivo del motor de base de datos, y por otro lado que pasa si una persona es hipocondriaca y tiene mas de 20 datos clínicos? los historiales clínicos deben ser presentados en vertical y se debe especificar en que fecha se realizaron cada estudio clínico... eso nos ayuda a determinar si ya es tiempo de repetir un estudio. saludos.

Comment: Hola amigo y un gusto de verdad y mis respetos para ti que eres dos cosas de gran magnitud, con respecto a los datos requeridos utilizo las tablas facturas, detalle factura, clientes y productos, la cual estoy consultado con inner join para unir los productos(estudios que se realizo el usuario en un solo registro o linea de mi consulta) para luego poder recibirlo e imprimirlo en mi tabla por medio de php, si hago la impresion de esos datos pero por ejemplo si tal usuario se vino a checar 5 estudios me lo imprme 5 veces en vez de que solo imprima una vez con los 5 estudios que se realizo.

Comment: Agrupa por cliente con `GROUP BY clientes.id_cliente` y para la columna usa `group_concat(productos.nombre_producto)`.

Comment: Hola mi amigo, primero que nada muchisimas gracias por tus comentarios y respuestas, de verdad que me ayudo muchisimo la verdad y si ya me salio como yo queria de verdad eres una chingoneria. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda mi amigo. saludos y gracias.

Comment: @labqc el problema es el despliegue en la tabla, no necesitas imprimir el nombre del cliente ... puedes imprimirlo como parte de la cabecera de la factura.  y te ahorras espacios en el detalle... igual puedes aplicar cada estudio como un servicio por separado con un costo por separado... para la contabilidad  y estadística vendría como anillo al dedo...